# using api gateway in docker container to navigate instead of localhost:port

Tags: c#, .net, docker

I have API gateway (ocelot) up and running.
some of my services running inside docker are:

*docker-compose.override.yml*

```
services:
  gateway:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:5000
    ports:
      - "6000:5000"

  serviceone:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:5100
    ports:
      - "6100:5100"

  servicetwo:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:5200
    ports:
      - "6200:5200"
```

*ocelot.json*

```
{
  "ReRoutes": [
   {
       ... ommited for clarity
   }],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "http://gateway:5000"
  }
}
```

Containers working and I'm able to be rerouted using ocelot api gateway by using

```
http://localhost:5000/whatever-url-I-registered-in-ocelot
```

I tried to change this and to navigate through http://gateway:5000 but I'm getting

> server IP address could not be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to http://localhost:6000 (on local machine) http://gateway:6000 from containers.

you're mapping localport 6000 to 5000 in the container.

It's not clear where you're trying to reach it **from**

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need to add hosts entry to map "gateway" to localhost (127.0.0.1) - assuming you're trying to run this locally...

Find hosts file; on Linux this will be `/etc/hosts`, on windows `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`; and add hosts entry as follows:

```
127.0.0.1 gateway
```

Other thing to check is your port binding which is "6000:5000". This means 6000 on the host machine to 5000 in the container - means you might need to use port 6000 from the host...